# What is the use of Assignment expressions in python 3.8

Tags: python-3.8

Bit to know new syntax **:=** (the walrus operator) that assigns values. Anyone explain with brief example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets take the first example from the [What's new in 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html) documentation:

```
if (n := len(a)) > 10:
    print(f"List is too long ({n} elements, expected <= 10)")
```

"Normal" assignment is a *statement*, it can't be used as part of expressions. Without the expression-assignment ("walrus") operator the above example would have to be something like

```
n = len(a)
if n > 10:
    print(f"List is too long ({n} elements, expected <= 10)")
```

With the expression-assignment you can combine the assignment to `n` with the condition.